# Convert List<Object> to Map<String, List<Object>> in kotlin

Tags: android, performance, dictionary, collections, kotlin

I have a Collection of certain Object in Kotlin, and I'd like to map objects that have a common value in one of their attributes, I've tried using the Collenction utilities from Kotlin, but can't find a way to get a List as the  value for a certain key, is this possible without too much code?

Basically, what I need is to get this: List --> Map>
Where the String key is a value from a certain property of the Object.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) does just the sort of thing you're looking for.

```
collection.groupBy { x -> x.getKey() }
```